# Pom dependency front end - ejb client

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, pom.xml

Hi i'm a junior developer and  i'm working on this project, like the title i can't link my ejb-client with the front-end (also back-end) is my first solo project, i wrote everything but i have some problems with the poms, on the foot of the topic there's the detailed maven error (sorry for format my first thread here)

Ejb Client Pom

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProgettoAziende</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>progettoaziende-ejb-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>progettoaziende-ejb-client</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibatis-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Front End pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProgettoAziende</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>progettoaziende-frontend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>progetto aziende-frontend</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>progettoaziende-frontend</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
            <artifactId>progettoaziende-ejb-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Json Mapping -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

SUPER POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProgettoAziende</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>ProgettoAziende</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<modules>
    <module>progettoaziende-be-ear</module>
    <module>progettoaziende-ejb-client</module>
    <module>progettoaziende-be-ejb</module>
    <module>progettoaziende-frontend</module>
</modules>
  <properties>

    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>${encoding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${encoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

    <build>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>



<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
    <artifactId>progettoaziende-be-ear</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
        <artifactId>progettoaziende-ejb-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
        <artifactId>progettoaziende-be-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
        <artifactId>progettoaziende-frontend</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

EJB Module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProgettoAziende</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
    <artifactId>progettoaziende-be-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>progettoaziende-be-ejb</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibatis-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
            <artifactId>progettoaziende-ejb-client</artifactId>
            <type>ejb-client</type>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.726</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

MAVEN ERROR (I tried to compile the back-end module here, but is the same kind of problem with the front end, same error)

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building progettoaziende-be-ejb 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.422 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-19T14:33:24+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project progettoaziende-be-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project it.isc:progettoaziende-be-ejb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

EDIT: FULL ERROR TRACE

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ProgettoAziende
[INFO] progettoaziende-ejb-client
[INFO] progettoaziende-be-ejb
[INFO] progetto aziende-frontend
[INFO] progettoaziende-be-ear
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ProgettoAziende 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ProgettoAziende ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ProgettoAziende ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\pom.xml to C:\Users\DEV\.m2\repository\it\isc\ProgettoAziende\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\ProgettoAziende-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building progettoaziende-ejb-client 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 17 source files to C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.progettoaziende.ejb.client.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\target\progettoaziende-ejb-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ progettoaziende-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\target\progettoaziende-ejb-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\DEV\.m2\repository\it\isc\progettoaziende-ejb-client\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\progettoaziende-ejb-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\DEV\workspace\ProgettoAziende\progettoaziende-ejb-client\pom.xml to C:\Users\DEV\.m2\repository\it\isc\progettoaziende-ejb-client\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\progettoaziende-ejb-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building progettoaziende-be-ejb 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ProgettoAziende .................................... SUCCESS [  1.584 s]
[INFO] progettoaziende-ejb-client ......................... SUCCESS [  9.071 s]
[INFO] progettoaziende-be-ejb ............................. FAILURE [  0.160 s]
[INFO] progetto aziende-frontend .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] progettoaziende-be-ear ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.579 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-20T09:40:23+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project progettoaziende-be-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project it.isc:progettoaziende-be-ejb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project progettoaziende-be-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project it.isc:progettoaziende-be-ejb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project it.isc:progettoaziende-be-ejb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact it.isc:progettoaziende-ejb-client:jar:client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434)
    ... 27 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :progettoaziende-be-ejb
```

Comment: Your `<project` tag isn't complete. Was it a typo?

Comment: @aribeiro sorry i forgot to paste the complete code

Comment: did you "mvn clean install" the parent module?

Comment: @FedericoSerini, as Korgen suggested, try executing the clean-install command on your parent module. I've created a simple project using the *pom.xml* files you've posted and no error occurs.

Comment: @Korgen Already tried before opening this thread, i'll post all the error trace (only ejb client compiles)

Comment: @aribeiro  Already tried before opening this thread, i'll post all the error trace (only ejb client compiles)

Comment: @FedericoSerini, then please provide also your parent *pom.xml*.

Comment: @aribeiro done thank you for help

Comment: @FedericoSerini, the problem is on your *progettoaziende-be-ejb* module. Can you also provide its *pom.xml*?

Comment: @aribeiro  done, provided

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm assuming you're using the *progettoaziende-ejb-client* module as container for your EJB API interfaces, in order to share with both your *progettoaziende-frontend* and *progettoaziende-be-ejb* modules.

As you probably already figured out, you're not generating your EJB client correctly.

Instead of having two modules, *progettoaziende-be-ejb* and *progettoaziende-ejb-client*, you should only have one module: *progettoaziende-be-ejb*.

Then, on the *pom.xml* of this module, you'd say it is an EJB module and configure your Maven EJB Plugin in order to [generate an EJB client](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html):

```
<artifactId>progettoaziende-be-ejb</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

(...)

<build>
    (...)
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                (...)

                <generateClient>true</generateClient>

                (...)
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    (...)
</build>
```

Afterwards, in order to specify what your EJB client jar should or shouldn't contain, you could make use of the ***clientIncludes*** and ***clientExcludes*** elements:

```
<build>

    (...)

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                (...)

                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <clientIncludes>
                    <!-- this will include all files and directories under com/foo/bar -->
                    <clientInclude>com/foo/bar/**</clientInclude>
                    <!-- this will include all files and directories under com/foo/acme -->
                    <clientInclude>com/foo/acme/**</clientInclude>
                    <!-- this will include all files under com/example -->
                    <clientInclude>com/example/*</clientInclude>
                </clientIncludes>
                <clientExcludes>
                    <!-- this will exclude all files under com/example -->
                    <clientExclude>com/example/*</clientExclude>
                    <!-- this will exclude all files and directories with the name
                        sparrow under com/jack -->
                    <clientExclude>com/jack/**/sparrow</clientExclude>
              </clientExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    (...)

</build>
```

Finally, you should:

- Remove the dependency *progettoaziende-ejb-client* from the *pom.xml* of *progettoaziende-be-ejb* module;
- Modify the dependency *progettoaziende-ejb-client* on the *pom.xml* of your WAR module from:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
      <artifactId>progettoaziende-ejb-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  to:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>it.isc</groupId>
      <artifactId>progettoaziende-be-ejb</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>ejb-client</type>
  </dependency>
  ```